# SQL Error [156] [S0001]: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'union'

Tags: sql, union

```
WITH a AS
(
    SELECT 
        ii.RPTCategory AS Cat,
        YEAR(ii.CreateDate) AS CatYear, MONTH(ii.CreateDate) AS CatMonth,
        COUNT(*) AS CatNo
    FROM 
        InsInvoice ii 
    WHERE
        ii.RPTCategory IN ('12')
    GROUP BY
        ii.RPTCategory, YEAR(ii.CreateDate), MONTH(ii.CreateDate)
),
b AS
(
    SELECT 
        ii.Category AS Cat,
        YEAR(ii.CreateDate) AS CatYear, MONTH(ii.CreateDate) AS CatMonth,
        COUNT(*) AS CatNo
    FROM 
        InsInvoice ii 
    WHERE
        ii.Category IN ('41')
    GROUP BY
        ii.Category, YEAR(ii.CreateDate), MONTH(ii.CreateDate)
)
SELECT *
FROM 
    (a UNION b)
```

I get the error

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword union

All searches I've done, the user encounters the error when using `order by` within their sub select statements but I'm not doing that.  I've tried splitting this out into sub select statements instead of using the with clause but I get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

The correct use of `union` would be:

```
select a.*
from a
union
select b.*
from b;
```

Comment: That worked.  I'll accept as soon as it allows.  And thank you for cleaning up my original edit!